# How to save a frame using QMediaPlayer?

Tags: qt, qmediaplayer

I want to save an image of a frame from a `QMediaPlayer`. After reading the documentation, I understood that I should use [`QVideoProbe`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvideoprobe.html). I am using the following code :

```
QMediaPlayer *player = new QMediaPlayer();
QVideoProbe *probe   = new QVideoProbe;

connect(probe, SIGNAL(videoFrameProbed(QVideoFrame)), this, SLOT(processFrame(QVideoFrame)));

qDebug()<<probe->setSource(player); // Returns true, hopefully.

player->setVideoOutput(myVideoSurface);
player->setMedia(QUrl::fromLocalFile("observation.mp4"));
player->play(); // Start receving frames as they get presented to myVideoSurface
```

But unfortunately, `probe->setSource(player)` always returns `false` for me, and thus my slot `processFrame` is not triggered.

What am I doing wrong ? Does anybody have a working example of `QVideoProbe` ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You're not doing anything wrong. As @DYangu pointed out, your media object instance does not support monitoring video. I had the same problem (and same for [`QAudioProbe`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qaudioprobe.html) but it doesn't interest us here). I found a solution by looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30800772/how-to-grab-video-frames-in-qt) answer and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26229633/use-of-qabstractvideosurface).

The main idea is to **subclass [QAbstractVideoSurface](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractvideosurface.html)**. Once you've done that, it will call the method `QAbstractVideoSurface::present(const QVideoFrame & frame)` of your implementation of `QAbstractVideoSurface` and you will be able to process the frames of your video.

As it is said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26229633/use-of-qabstractvideosurface), usually you will just need to reimplement two methods :

1. [supportedPixelFormats](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qabstractvideosurface.html#supportedPixelFormats) so that the producer can select an appropriate format for the `QVideoFrame`
2. [present](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qabstractvideosurface.html#present) which allows to display the frame

But at the time, I searched in the Qt source code and happily found [this piece of code](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qt-multimedia-videowidget-videowidgetsurface-cpp.html) which helped me to do a full implementation. So, **here is the full code** for using a "video frame grabber".

**VideoFrameGrabber.cpp :**

```
#include "VideoFrameGrabber.h"

#include <QtWidgets>
#include <qabstractvideosurface.h>
#include <qvideosurfaceformat.h>

VideoFrameGrabber::VideoFrameGrabber(QWidget *widget, QObject *parent)
    : QAbstractVideoSurface(parent)
    , widget(widget)
    , imageFormat(QImage::Format_Invalid)
{
}

QList<QVideoFrame::PixelFormat> VideoFrameGrabber::supportedPixelFormats(QAbstractVideoBuffer::HandleType handleType) const
{
    Q_UNUSED(handleType);
    return QList<QVideoFrame::PixelFormat>()
        << QVideoFrame::Format_ARGB32
        << QVideoFrame::Format_ARGB32_Premultiplied
        << QVideoFrame::Format_RGB32
        << QVideoFrame::Format_RGB24
        << QVideoFrame::Format_RGB565
        << QVideoFrame::Format_RGB555
        << QVideoFrame::Format_ARGB8565_Premultiplied
        << QVideoFrame::Format_BGRA32
        << QVideoFrame::Format_BGRA32_Premultiplied
        << QVideoFrame::Format_BGR32
        << QVideoFrame::Format_BGR24
        << QVideoFrame::Format_BGR565
        << QVideoFrame::Format_BGR555
        << QVideoFrame::Format_BGRA5658_Premultiplied
        << QVideoFrame::Format_AYUV444
        << QVideoFrame::Format_AYUV444_Premultiplied
        << QVideoFrame::Format_YUV444
        << QVideoFrame::Format_YUV420P
        << QVideoFrame::Format_YV12
        << QVideoFrame::Format_UYVY
        << QVideoFrame::Format_YUYV
        << QVideoFrame::Format_NV12
        << QVideoFrame::Format_NV21
        << QVideoFrame::Format_IMC1
        << QVideoFrame::Format_IMC2
        << QVideoFrame::Format_IMC3
        << QVideoFrame::Format_IMC4
        << QVideoFrame::Format_Y8
        << QVideoFrame::Format_Y16
        << QVideoFrame::Format_Jpeg
        << QVideoFrame::Format_CameraRaw
        << QVideoFrame::Format_AdobeDng;
}

bool VideoFrameGrabber::isFormatSupported(const QVideoSurfaceFormat &format) const
{
    const QImage::Format imageFormat = QVideoFrame::imageFormatFromPixelFormat(format.pixelFormat());
    const QSize size = format.frameSize();

    return imageFormat != QImage::Format_Invalid
            && !size.isEmpty()
            && format.handleType() == QAbstractVideoBuffer::NoHandle;
}

bool VideoFrameGrabber::start(const QVideoSurfaceFormat &format)
{
    const QImage::Format imageFormat = QVideoFrame::imageFormatFromPixelFormat(format.pixelFormat());
    const QSize size = format.frameSize();

    if (imageFormat != QImage::Format_Invalid && !size.isEmpty()) {
        this->imageFormat = imageFormat;
        imageSize = size;
        sourceRect = format.viewport();

        QAbstractVideoSurface::start(format);

        widget->updateGeometry();
        updateVideoRect();

        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

void VideoFrameGrabber::stop()
{
    currentFrame = QVideoFrame();
    targetRect = QRect();

    QAbstractVideoSurface::stop();

    widget->update();
}

bool VideoFrameGrabber::present(const QVideoFrame &frame)
{
    if (frame.isValid()) 
    {
        QVideoFrame cloneFrame(frame);
        cloneFrame.map(QAbstractVideoBuffer::ReadOnly);
        const QImage image(cloneFrame.bits(),
                           cloneFrame.width(),
                           cloneFrame.height(),
                           QVideoFrame::imageFormatFromPixelFormat(cloneFrame .pixelFormat()));
        emit frameAvailable(image); // this is very important
        cloneFrame.unmap();
    }

    if (surfaceFormat().pixelFormat() != frame.pixelFormat()
            || surfaceFormat().frameSize() != frame.size()) {
        setError(IncorrectFormatError);
        stop();

        return false;
    } else {
        currentFrame = frame;

        widget->repaint(targetRect);

        return true;
    }
}

void VideoFrameGrabber::updateVideoRect()
{
    QSize size = surfaceFormat().sizeHint();
    size.scale(widget->size().boundedTo(size), Qt::KeepAspectRatio);

    targetRect = QRect(QPoint(0, 0), size);
    targetRect.moveCenter(widget->rect().center());
}

void VideoFrameGrabber::paint(QPainter *painter)
{
    if (currentFrame.map(QAbstractVideoBuffer::ReadOnly)) {
        const QTransform oldTransform = painter->transform();

        if (surfaceFormat().scanLineDirection() == QVideoSurfaceFormat::BottomToTop) {
           painter->scale(1, -1);
           painter->translate(0, -widget->height());
        }

        QImage image(
                currentFrame.bits(),
                currentFrame.width(),
                currentFrame.height(),
                currentFrame.bytesPerLine(),
                imageFormat);

        painter->drawImage(targetRect, image, sourceRect);

        painter->setTransform(oldTransform);

        currentFrame.unmap();
    }
}
```

**VideoFrameGrabber.h**

```
#ifndef VIDEOFRAMEGRABBER_H
#define VIDEOFRAMEGRABBER_H

#include <QtWidgets>

class VideoFrameGrabber : public QAbstractVideoSurface
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    VideoFrameGrabber(QWidget *widget, QObject *parent = 0);

    QList<QVideoFrame::PixelFormat> supportedPixelFormats(
            QAbstractVideoBuffer::HandleType handleType = QAbstractVideoBuffer::NoHandle) const;
    bool isFormatSupported(const QVideoSurfaceFormat &format) const;

    bool start(const QVideoSurfaceFormat &format);
    void stop();

    bool present(const QVideoFrame &frame);

    QRect videoRect() const { return targetRect; }
    void updateVideoRect();

    void paint(QPainter *painter);

private:
    QWidget *widget;
    QImage::Format imageFormat;
    QRect targetRect;
    QSize imageSize;
    QRect sourceRect;
    QVideoFrame currentFrame;

signals:
    void frameAvailable(QImage frame);
};
#endif //VIDEOFRAMEGRABBER_H
```

**Note** : in the .h, you will see I added a [signal](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html) taking an image as a parameter. **This will allow you to process your frame** anywhere in your code. At the time, this signal took a `QImage` as a parameter, but you can of course take a `QVideoFrame` if you want to.

---

Now, we are ready to use this video frame grabber:

```
QMediaPlayer* player = new QMediaPlayer(this);
// no more QVideoProbe 
VideoFrameGrabber* grabber = new VideoFrameGrabber(this);
player->setVideoOutput(grabber);

connect(grabber, SIGNAL(frameAvailable(QImage)), this, SLOT(processFrame(QImage)));
```

Now you just have to declare a slot named `processFrame(QImage image)` and you will receive a `QImage` each time you will enter the method [present](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qabstractvideosurface.html#present) of your `VideoFrameGrabber`.

I hope that this will help you!

Comment: some stuipid question, before I used QWIdget to show video 
`player->setVideoOutput(ui->videoWidget);`

now I  must write as following ?
`player = new QMediaPlayer(this);
probe = new VideoFrameGrabber(ui->videoWidget, this);
player->setVideoOutput(probe);`

Comment: Just this : `player = new QMediaPlayer(this); 
probe = new VideoFrameGrabber(this);
 player->setVideoOutput(probe);`

Comment: Hello @IAmInPLS , the frames are accessible but the video which was rendered in videoWidget is not visible now, videoWidget is completely black. How can we resolve the issue ?

Comment: Thanks for this! I hit a bug recently where the frames would be corrupted on a slower machine. I had to use `emit frameAvailable(image.copy());` to fix this. The QImage was sent between threads.

Comment: Your idea is fine but how I am supposed to play the video in a QVideoWidget if the mediaPlayer output is set to videosurface ?

Comment: in function bool VideoFrameGrabber::present(const QVideoFrame &frame),  could be problem with  construct QImage, and we can use constructor with more parameters 

const QImage image(cloneFrame.bits(),
                           cloneFrame.width(),
                           cloneFrame.height(),
                           cloneFrame.bytesPerLine(),                           QVideoFrame::imageFormatFromPixelFormat(cloneFrame.pixelFormat()));

Comment: @taimoor1990 Since Qt 5.15, `QMediaPlayer::setVideoOutput` has an overload that can take a list of surfaces, so you can pass both `videoWidget->videoSurface()` for rendering + any other surfaces for processing. There's an example of exactly that in my alternative implementation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68088990/616460).

Comment: @IAmInPLS ^ Qt 5.15 finally added a multiple-surface `setVideoOutput` to `QMediaPlayer`, so it's possible now to eliminate all the widget forwarding and repainting logic from custom surfaces now and just add the `QVideoWidget`s surface to the player's output list directly instead (see my answer for details). Also I haven't tried Qt6 yet but I've heard the multimedia framework has been significantly reworked, which I hope is a good thing. It's been kind of a mess so far.

Answer (score 2):

***TL;DR:** https://gist.github.com/JC3/a7bab65acbd7659d1e57103d2b0021ba (only file)*

---

I had a similar issue (5.15.2; although in my case I was on Windows, was definitely using the DirectShow back-end, the probe attachment was returning true, the sample grabber was in the graph, but the callback wasn't firing).

I [never figured it out](https://forum.qt.io/topic/102436/qvideoprobe-not-emitting-videoframeprobed-signal/13) but needed to get something working so I kludged one out of a `QAbstractVideoSurface`, and it's been working well so far. It's a bit simpler than some of the other implementations in this post, and it's all in one file.

Note that Qt 5.15 or higher is required if you intend to both process frames *and* play them back with this, since the multi-surface `QMediaPlayer::setVideoOutput` wasn't added until 5.15. If all you want to do is process video you can still use the code below as a template for pre-5.15, just gut the `formatSource_` parts.

### Code:

[VideoProbeSurface.h](https://gist.github.com/JC3/a7bab65acbd7659d1e57103d2b0021ba) (the only file; link is to Gist)

```
#ifndef VIDEOPROBESURFACE_H
#define VIDEOPROBESURFACE_H

#include <QAbstractVideoSurface>
#include <QVideoSurfaceFormat>

class VideoProbeSurface : public QAbstractVideoSurface {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    VideoProbeSurface (QObject *parent = nullptr)
        : QAbstractVideoSurface(parent)
        , formatSource_(nullptr)
    {
    }
    void setFormatSource (QAbstractVideoSurface *source) {
        formatSource_ = source;
    }
    QList<QVideoFrame::PixelFormat> supportedPixelFormats (QAbstractVideoBuffer::HandleType type) const override {
        return formatSource_ ? formatSource_->supportedPixelFormats(type)
                             : QList<QVideoFrame::PixelFormat>();
    }
    QVideoSurfaceFormat nearestFormat (const QVideoSurfaceFormat &format) const override {
        return formatSource_ ? formatSource_->nearestFormat(format)
                             : QAbstractVideoSurface::nearestFormat(format);
    }
    bool present (const QVideoFrame &frame) override {
        emit videoFrameProbed(frame);
        return true;
    }
signals:
    void videoFrameProbed (const QVideoFrame &frame);
private:
    QAbstractVideoSurface *formatSource_;
};

#endif // VIDEOPROBESURFACE_H
```

I went for the quickest-to-write implementation possible so it just forwards supported pixel formats from another surface (my intent was to both probe *and* play back to a `QVideoWidget`) and you get whatever format you get. I just needed to grab subimages into `QImage`s though, which handles most common formats. But you could modify this to force any formats you want (e.g. you might want to just return formats supported by `QImage` or filter out source formats *not* supported by `QImage)`, etc.).

Example set up:

```
 QMediaPlayer *player = ...;
 QVideoWidget *widget = ...;

 // forward surface formats provided by the video widget:
 VideoProbeSurface *probe = new VideoProbeSurface(...);
 probe->setFormatSource(widget->videoSurface());

 // same signal signature as QVideoProbe's signal:
 connect(probe, &VideoProbeSurface::videoFrameProbed, ...);

 // the key move is to render to both the widget (for viewing)
 // and probe (for processing). fortunately, QMediaPlayer can
 // take a list:
 player->setVideoOutput({ widget->videoSurface(), probe });
```

### Notes

The only really sketchy thing I had to do was `const_cast` the `QVideoFrame` on the receiver side (for read-only access), since `QVideoFrame::map()` isn't `const`:

```
    if (const_cast<QVideoFrame&>(frame).map(QAbstractVideoBuffer::ReadOnly)) {
        ...;
        const_cast<QVideoFrame&>(frame).unmap();
    }
```

But the real `QVideoProbe` would make you do the same thing so, I don't know what's up with that -- it's a strange API. I ran some tests with sw, native hw, and copy-back hw renderers and decoders and `map`/`unmap` in read mode seem to be functioning OK, so, whatever.

Performance-wise, the video will bog down if you spend too much time in the callback, so design accordingly. However, I didn't test `QueuedConnection`, so I don't know if that'd still have the issue (although the fact that the signal parameter is a reference would make me wary of trying it, as well as conceivable issues with the GPU releasing the memory before the slot ends up being called). I don't know how `QVideoProbe` behaves in this regard, either. I do know that, at least on my machine, I can pack and queue Full HD (1920 x 1080) resolution `QImage`s to a thread pool for processing without slowing down the video.

You probably also want to implement some sort of auto-unmapper utility object for exception safe `unmap()`, etc. But again, that's not unique to this, same thing you'd have to do with `QVideoProbe`.

So hopefully that helps somebody else.

### Example QImage Use

PS, example of packing arbitrarily-formatted `QVideoFrame`s into a `QImage` in:

```
void MyVideoProcessor::onFrameProbed(const QVideoFrame &frame) {

    if (const_cast<QVideoFrame&>(frame).map(QAbstractVideoBuffer::ReadOnly)) {
        auto imageFormat = QVideoFrame::imageFormatFromPixelFormat(frame.pixelFormat());
        
        QImage image(frame.bits(), frame.width(), frame.height(), frame.bytesPerLine(), imageFormat);

        // *if* you want to use this elsewhere you must force detach:
        image = image.copy();
        // but if you don't need to use it past unmap(), you can just
        // use the original image instead of a copy.

        // <---- now do whatever with the image, e.g. save() it.

        // if you *haven't* copied the image, then, before unmapping,
        // kill any internal data pointers just to be safe:
        image = QImage();

        const_cast<QVideoFrame&>(frame).unmap();
    }

}
```

Notes about that:

- Constructing a `QImage` directly from the data is fast and essentially free: no copies are done.
- The data buffers are only technically valid between `map` and `unmap`, so if you intend to use the `QImage` outside of that scope, you'll want to use `copy()` (or anything else that forces a detach) to force a deep copy.
- You also probably want to ensure that the original not-copied `QImage` is destructed before calling `unmap`. It's unlikely to cause problems but it's always a good idea to minimize how many invalid pointers are hanging around at any given time, and also the `QImage` docs say "The buffer must remain valid throughout the life of the QImage and all copies that have not been modified or otherwise detached from the original buffer". Best to be strict about it.

Answer (score 1):

After [Qt QVideoProbe documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvideoprobe.html#setSource):

> ```
> bool QVideoProbe::setSource(QMediaObject *mediaObject)
> ```
>
> Starts monitoring the given mediaObject.
>
> If there is no media object associated with `mediaObject`, or if it is
>   zero, this probe will be deactivated and this function wil return
>   true.
>
> If the media object instance does not support monitoring video, this
>   function will return false.
>
> Any previously monitored objects will no longer be monitored. Passing
>   in the same object will be ignored, but monitoring will continue.

So it seems your "media object instance does not support monitoring video"

Answer (score 1):

It is now 2023, and the latest Qt version is Qt6.6. According to [official information](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtmultimedia-changes-qt6.html).

> The Qt Multimedia module in Qt 6 replaces the Qt Multimedia module from Qt 5.x. QVideoProbe has been removed.

But now we have an easier way to save frames output by QMediaPlayer. We should use QVideoSink.

Here is my example:

```cpp
QMediaPlayer* backgroundVideoPlayer = new QMediaPlayer;
QVideoSink* backgroundVideoSink = new QVideoSink;

backgroundVideoPlayer->setLoops(QMediaPlayer::Infinite);
backgroundVideoPlayer->setVideoOutput(backgroundVideoSink);

connect(backgroundVideoSink, &QVideoSink::videoFrameChanged, this, [&](const QVideoFrame &frame){
    /*Add your frame handling code here*/
    QPixmap backgroundVideoFrame = QPixmap::fromImage(frame.toImage());
});

backgroundVideoPlayer->setSource(QUrl::fromLocalFile("test.mp4"));
backgroundVideoPlayer->play();
```