# PyQt5 Access Frames with QmediaPlayer

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qmediaplayer, qvideowidget

I am creating a program to play videos and then process them. I am able to play the videos with `QMediaPlayer`. How do I access specific frames as images or something similar. My end goal would be to format the video into a 4-d tensor of size [Num of frames, width_of_video, height_of_video, channels].

Here is the code that loads my video.:

```
self.clear_layout(self.vlayout)
videoItem = QVideoWidget()

self.mediaPlayer = QMediaPlayer(None, QMediaPlayer.VideoSurface)
self.mediaPlayer.durationChanged.connect(self.update_duration)     
self.mediaPlayer.positionChanged.connect(self.update_slider_position)

self.vlayout.addWidget(videoItem)
self.mediaPlayer.setVideoOutput(videoItem)
local = QUrl.fromLocalFile(self.video_paths)
media = QMediaContent(local)
self.mediaPlayer.setMedia(media)
self.play_video()
```

Comment: Can you share your existing code?

Comment: Just added some of my code.

Comment: I am very sorry and thank you for the help. The project moved in a different direction and for now and I am just working with images. I will be using this in the near future though when we get back to videos. Thank you very much and sorry for not responding, I don't check stackoverflow very often.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a working example that I converted to Python from the C++ version available in this question: [How to save a frame using QMediaPlayer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37724602/how-to-save-a-frame-using-qmediaplayer)

```
import sys
import uuid

import PyQt5
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QObject, QUrl, QRect, pyqtSignal, QPoint
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter, QImage
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication, QMainWindow, QGridLayout, QToolBar, QAction
from PyQt5.QtMultimedia import QMediaPlayer, QMediaContent, QAbstractVideoBuffer, \
    QVideoFrame, QVideoSurfaceFormat, QAbstractVideoSurface
from PyQt5.QtMultimediaWidgets import QVideoWidget


class VideoFrameGrabber(QAbstractVideoSurface):
    frameAvailable = pyqtSignal(QImage)

    def __init__(self, widget: QWidget, parent: QObject):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.widget = widget

    def supportedPixelFormats(self, handleType):
        return [QVideoFrame.Format_ARGB32, QVideoFrame.Format_ARGB32_Premultiplied,
                QVideoFrame.Format_RGB32, QVideoFrame.Format_RGB24, QVideoFrame.Format_RGB565,
                QVideoFrame.Format_RGB555, QVideoFrame.Format_ARGB8565_Premultiplied,
                QVideoFrame.Format_BGRA32, QVideoFrame.Format_BGRA32_Premultiplied, QVideoFrame.Format_BGR32,
                QVideoFrame.Format_BGR24, QVideoFrame.Format_BGR565, QVideoFrame.Format_BGR555,
                QVideoFrame.Format_BGRA5658_Premultiplied, QVideoFrame.Format_AYUV444,
                QVideoFrame.Format_AYUV444_Premultiplied, QVideoFrame.Format_YUV444,
                QVideoFrame.Format_YUV420P, QVideoFrame.Format_YV12, QVideoFrame.Format_UYVY,
                QVideoFrame.Format_YUYV, QVideoFrame.Format_NV12, QVideoFrame.Format_NV21,
                QVideoFrame.Format_IMC1, QVideoFrame.Format_IMC2, QVideoFrame.Format_IMC3,
                QVideoFrame.Format_IMC4, QVideoFrame.Format_Y8, QVideoFrame.Format_Y16,
                QVideoFrame.Format_Jpeg, QVideoFrame.Format_CameraRaw, QVideoFrame.Format_AdobeDng]

    def isFormatSupported(self, format):
        imageFormat = QVideoFrame.imageFormatFromPixelFormat(format.pixelFormat())
        size = format.frameSize()

        return imageFormat != QImage.Format_Invalid and not size.isEmpty() and \
               format.handleType() == QAbstractVideoBuffer.NoHandle

    def start(self, format: QVideoSurfaceFormat):
        imageFormat = QVideoFrame.imageFormatFromPixelFormat(format.pixelFormat())
        size = format.frameSize()

        if imageFormat != QImage.Format_Invalid and not size.isEmpty():
            self.imageFormat = imageFormat
            self.imageSize = size
            self.sourceRect = format.viewport()

            super().start(format)

            self.widget.updateGeometry()
            self.updateVideoRect()

            return True
        else:
            return False

    def stop(self):
        self.currentFrame = QVideoFrame()
        self.targetRect = QRect()

        super().stop()

        self.widget.update()

    def present(self, frame):
        if frame.isValid():
            cloneFrame = QVideoFrame(frame)
            cloneFrame.map(QAbstractVideoBuffer.ReadOnly)
            image = QImage(cloneFrame.bits(), cloneFrame.width(), cloneFrame.height(),
                           QVideoFrame.imageFormatFromPixelFormat(cloneFrame.pixelFormat()))
            self.frameAvailable.emit(image)  # this is very important
            cloneFrame.unmap()

        if self.surfaceFormat().pixelFormat() != frame.pixelFormat() or \
                self.surfaceFormat().frameSize() != frame.size():
            self.setError(QAbstractVideoSurface.IncorrectFormatError)
            self.stop()

            return False
        else:
            self.currentFrame = frame

            self.widget.repaint(self.targetRect)

            return True

    def updateVideoRect(self):
        size = self.surfaceFormat().sizeHint()
        size.scale(self.widget.size().boundedTo(size), Qt.KeepAspectRatio)

        self.targetRect = QRect(QPoint(0, 0), size)
        self.targetRect.moveCenter(self.widget.rect().center())

    def paint(self, painter):
        if self.currentFrame.map(QAbstractVideoBuffer.ReadOnly):
            oldTransform = self.painter.transform()

        if self.surfaceFormat().scanLineDirection() == QVideoSurfaceFormat.BottomToTop:
            self.painter.scale(1, -1)
            self.painter.translate(0, -self.widget.height())

        image = QImage(self.currentFrame.bits(), self.currentFrame.width(), self.currentFrame.height(),
                       self.currentFrame.bytesPerLine(), self.imageFormat)

        self.painter.drawImage(self.targetRect, image, self.sourceRect)

        self.painter.setTransform(oldTransform)

        self.currentFrame.unmap()


class App(QApplication):
    def __init__(self, sys_argv):
        super().__init__(sys_argv)

        # Show main window
        self.view = QMainWindow()

        self.centralWidget = QWidget(self.view)

        self.gridLayout = QGridLayout(self.centralWidget)
        self.gridLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.gridLayout.setSpacing(0)

        self.video_item = QVideoWidget()

        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.video_item)

        self.view.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)

        self.mediaPlayer = QMediaPlayer(None, QMediaPlayer.VideoSurface)

        self.grabber = VideoFrameGrabber(self.video_item, self)
        self.mediaPlayer.setVideoOutput(self.grabber)

        self.grabber.frameAvailable.connect(self.process_frame)

        self.mediaPlayer.durationChanged.connect(self.update_duration)
        self.mediaPlayer.positionChanged.connect(self.update_slider_position)

        local = QUrl.fromLocalFile('c:/temp/lorem.mp4')
        media = QMediaContent(local)
        self.mediaPlayer.setMedia(media)
        self.mediaPlayer.play()

        self.view.show()

    def process_frame(self, image):
        # Save image here
        image.save('c:/temp/{}.jpg'.format(str(uuid.uuid4())))

    def update_duration(self):
        pass

    def update_slider_position(self):
        pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    def except_hook(cls, exception, traceback):
        sys.__excepthook__(cls, exception, traceback)


    if hasattr(QtCore.Qt, 'AA_EnableHighDpiScaling'):
        PyQt5.QtWidgets.QApplication.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.AA_EnableHighDpiScaling, True)

    if hasattr(QtCore.Qt, 'AA_UseHighDpiPixmaps'):
        PyQt5.QtWidgets.QApplication.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.AA_UseHighDpiPixmaps, True)

    app = App(sys.argv)
    app.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.AA_EnableHighDpiScaling)

    sys.excepthook = except_hook
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: i had the same problem and this was perfectly working for me. however, i only want to retrieve certain frames (e.g. 10 frames before and after the current frame). is there a way for me to achieve that?