# PyQt5 grabbing current frame displays blank

Tags: python, pyqt5, qmediaplayer, qvideowidget

I'm new to PyQt and I'm trying to create a videoplayer that screenshots the current frame it retrieves. I implemented [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52388865/7774774) method for grabbing the videoframes in order to take screenshots and added it to a [videoplayer GUI](https://pythonprogramminglanguage.com/pyqt5-video-widget/). Here's how the GUI essentially looks like:

[image: pyqt videoplayer gui]

I created a trigger for the screenshot action in the [VideoWindow class](https://pythonprogramminglanguage.com/pyqt5-video-widget/) with the following code:

```
screenshotAction = QAction(QIcon('screenshot.png'), '&Screenshot', self)
screenshotAction.setShortcut('Ctrl+S')
screenshotAction.setStatusTip('Screenshot scenes')
screenshotAction.triggered.connect(self.screenshotCall)
```

I then took the implementation of the [VideoFrameGrabber class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52359924/pyqt5-access-frames-with-qmediaplayer/52388865#52388865) and called it in the screenshot function:

```
def screenshotCall(self):
        #Call video frame grabber
        self.grabber = VideoFrameGrabber(self.videoWidget, self)
        self.mediaPlayer.setVideoOutput(self.grabber)
        self.grabber.frameAvailable.connect(self.process_frame)
        self.mediaPlayer.setVideoOutput(self.videoWidget)
```

Complete code:

```
# PyQt5 Video player
#!/usr/bin/env python

from PyQt5.QtCore import QDir, Qt, QUrl, pyqtSignal, QPoint, QRect, QObject
from PyQt5.QtMultimedia import QMediaContent, QMediaPlayer, QVideoFrame, QAbstractVideoSurface, QAbstractVideoBuffer, QVideoSurfaceFormat
from PyQt5.QtMultimediaWidgets import QVideoWidget
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QFileDialog, QHBoxLayout, QLabel,
        QPushButton, QSizePolicy, QSlider, QStyle, QVBoxLayout, QWidget)
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow,QWidget, QPushButton, QAction
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon, QPainter, QImage
import sys
import os
import os.path as osp

class VideoFrameGrabber(QAbstractVideoSurface):
    frameAvailable = pyqtSignal(QImage)

    def __init__(self, widget: QWidget, parent: QObject):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.widget = widget
    def supportedPixelFormats(self, handleType):
        return [QVideoFrame.Format_ARGB32, QVideoFrame.Format_ARGB32_Premultiplied,
                QVideoFrame.Format_RGB32, QVideoFrame.Format_RGB24, QVideoFrame.Format_RGB565,
                QVideoFrame.Format_RGB555, QVideoFrame.Format_ARGB8565_Premultiplied,
                QVideoFrame.Format_BGRA32, QVideoFrame.Format_BGRA32_Premultiplied, QVideoFrame.Format_BGR32,
                QVideoFrame.Format_BGR24, QVideoFrame.Format_BGR565, QVideoFrame.Format_BGR555,
                QVideoFrame.Format_BGRA5658_Premultiplied, QVideoFrame.Format_AYUV444,
                QVideoFrame.Format_AYUV444_Premultiplied, QVideoFrame.Format_YUV444,
                QVideoFrame.Format_YUV420P, QVideoFrame.Format_YV12, QVideoFrame.Format_UYVY,
                QVideoFrame.Format_YUYV, QVideoFrame.Format_NV12, QVideoFrame.Format_NV21,
                QVideoFrame.Format_IMC1, QVideoFrame.Format_IMC2, QVideoFrame.Format_IMC3,
                QVideoFrame.Format_IMC4, QVideoFrame.Format_Y8, QVideoFrame.Format_Y16,
                QVideoFrame.Format_Jpeg, QVideoFrame.Format_CameraRaw, QVideoFrame.Format_AdobeDng]

    def isFormatSupported(self, format):
        imageFormat = QVideoFrame.imageFormatFromPixelFormat(format.pixelFormat())
        size = format.frameSize()

        return imageFormat != QImage.Format_Invalid and not size.isEmpty() and \
               format.handleType() == QAbstractVideoBuffer.NoHandle

    def start(self, format: QVideoSurfaceFormat):
        imageFormat = QVideoFrame.imageFormatFromPixelFormat(format.pixelFormat())
        size = format.frameSize()

        if imageFormat != QImage.Format_Invalid and not size.isEmpty():
            self.imageFormat = imageFormat
            self.imageSize = size
            self.sourceRect = format.viewport()

            super().start(format)

            self.widget.updateGeometry()
            self.updateVideoRect()

            return True
        else:
            return False

    def stop(self):
        self.currentFrame = QVideoFrame()
        self.targetRect = QRect()

        super().stop()

        self.widget.update()

    def present(self, frame):
        if frame.isValid():
            cloneFrame = QVideoFrame(frame)
            cloneFrame.map(QAbstractVideoBuffer.ReadOnly)
            image = QImage(cloneFrame.bits(), cloneFrame.width(), cloneFrame.height(),
                           QVideoFrame.imageFormatFromPixelFormat(cloneFrame.pixelFormat()))
            self.frameAvailable.emit(image)  # this is very important
            cloneFrame.unmap()

        if self.surfaceFormat().pixelFormat() != frame.pixelFormat() or \
                self.surfaceFormat().frameSize() != frame.size():
            self.setError(QAbstractVideoSurface.IncorrectFormatError)
            self.stop()

            return False
        else:
            self.currentFrame = frame
            self.widget.repaint(self.targetRect)

            return True

    def updateVideoRect(self):
        size = self.surfaceFormat().sizeHint()
        size.scale(self.widget.size().boundedTo(size), Qt.KeepAspectRatio)

        self.targetRect = QRect(QPoint(0, 0), size)
        self.targetRect.moveCenter(self.widget.rect().center())

    def paint(self, painter):
        if self.currentFrame.map(QAbstractVideoBuffer.ReadOnly):
            oldTransform = self.painter.transform()

        if self.surfaceFormat().scanLineDirection() == QVideoSurfaceFormat.BottomToTop:
            self.painter.scale(1, -1)
            self.painter.translate(0, -self.widget.height())

        image = QImage(self.currentFrame.bits(), self.currentFrame.width(), self.currentFrame.height(),
                       self.currentFrame.bytesPerLine(), self.imageFormat)

        self.painter.drawImage(self.targetRect, image, self.sourceRect)

        self.painter.setTransform(oldTransform)

        self.currentFrame.unmap()

class VideoWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(VideoWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setWindowTitle("PyQt Video Player Widget") 

        self.counter = 0
        self.mediaPlayer = QMediaPlayer(None, QMediaPlayer.VideoSurface)
        self.videoWidget = QVideoWidget()
        self.videoFrame = QVideoFrame()
        self.playButton = QPushButton()
        self.playButton.setEnabled(False)
        self.playButton.setIcon(self.style().standardIcon(QStyle.SP_MediaPlay))
        self.playButton.clicked.connect(self.play)

        self.positionSlider = QSlider(Qt.Horizontal)
        self.positionSlider.setRange(0, 0)
        self.positionSlider.sliderMoved.connect(self.setPosition)

        self.errorLabel = QLabel()
        self.errorLabel.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Preferred,
                QSizePolicy.Maximum)
        # Create new action
        openAction = QAction(QIcon('open.png'), '&Open', self)        
        openAction.setShortcut('Ctrl+O')
        openAction.setStatusTip('Open video')
        openAction.triggered.connect(self.openFile)

        # Create exit action
        exitAction = QAction(QIcon('quit.png'), '&Exit', self)        
        exitAction.setShortcut('Ctrl+Q')
        exitAction.setStatusTip('Exit application')
        exitAction.triggered.connect(self.exitCall)

        screenshotAction = QAction(QIcon('screenshot.png'), '&Screenshot', self)
        screenshotAction.setShortcut('Ctrl+S')
        screenshotAction.setStatusTip('Screenshot scenes')
        screenshotAction.triggered.connect(self.screenshotCall)

        # Create menu bar and add action
        menuBar = self.menuBar()
        fileMenu = menuBar.addMenu('&File')
        #fileMenu.addAction(newAction)
        fileMenu.addAction(openAction)
        fileMenu.addAction(screenshotAction)
        fileMenu.addAction(exitAction)


        # Create a widget for window contents
        wid = QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(wid)

        # Create layouts to place inside widget
        controlLayout = QHBoxLayout()
        controlLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        controlLayout.addWidget(self.playButton)
        controlLayout.addWidget(self.positionSlider)

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.videoWidget)
        layout.addLayout(controlLayout)
        layout.addWidget(self.errorLabel)

        # Set widget to contain window contents
        wid.setLayout(layout)


        self.mediaPlayer.setVideoOutput(self.videoWidget)
        self.mediaPlayer.stateChanged.connect(self.mediaStateChanged)
        self.mediaPlayer.positionChanged.connect(self.positionChanged)
        self.mediaPlayer.durationChanged.connect(self.durationChanged)
        self.mediaPlayer.error.connect(self.handleError)

    def openFile(self):
        fileName, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Open Movie",
                QDir.homePath())
        self.path = osp.dirname(str(fileName))
        if fileName != '':
            self.mediaPlayer.setMedia(
                    QMediaContent(QUrl.fromLocalFile(fileName)))
            self.playButton.setEnabled(True)

    def exitCall(self):
        sys.exit(app.exec_())

    def screenshotCall(self):
        #Call video frame grabber
        self.grabber = VideoFrameGrabber(self.videoWidget, self)
        self.mediaPlayer.setVideoOutput(self.grabber)
        self.mediaPlayer.pause()
        self.grabber.frameAvailable.connect(self.process_frame)
        self.errorLabel.setText("Taking a screenshot of image "+str(self.counter)+" ....")
        self.mediaPlayer.play()
        self.mediaPlayer.setVideoOutput(self.videoWidget)

    def play(self):
        if self.mediaPlayer.state() == QMediaPlayer.PlayingState:
            self.mediaPlayer.pause()
        else:
            self.mediaPlayer.play()

    def mediaStateChanged(self, state):
        if self.mediaPlayer.state() == QMediaPlayer.PlayingState:
            self.playButton.setIcon(
                    self.style().standardIcon(QStyle.SP_MediaPause))
        else:
            self.playButton.setIcon(
                    self.style().standardIcon(QStyle.SP_MediaPlay))

    def positionChanged(self, position):
        self.positionSlider.setValue(position)

    def durationChanged(self, duration):
        self.positionSlider.setRange(0, duration)

    def setPosition(self, position):
        self.mediaPlayer.setPosition(position)

    def handleError(self):
        self.playButton.setEnabled(False)
        self.errorLabel.setText("Error: " + self.mediaPlayer.errorString())

    def process_frame(self, image):
        # Save image here
        filename = "screenshot" + str(self.counter).zfill(6)
        self.path = 'C:/Desktop/temp'
        image.save(self.path+'/{}.png'.format(str(filename)))
        self.counter = self.counter+1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    player = VideoWindow()
    player.resize(720, 480)
    player.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

However, whenever I try taking a screenshot, the video display turns black. Based from the audio, the video is still playing, but the current display remains black all throughout the duration of the video from the moment the screenshot is taken. This happens for both when the player is paused and while it is still playing. I think it's because of the line `self.mediaPlayer.setVideoOutput(self.grabber)`, since it overwrites the current display on the screen with the grabber.

I've tried calling the videoWidget back and set it as the video output after the frame was grabbed, but it seems to overwrite the grabber and does not produce any screenshots at all.

Is there a way for me to simultaneously take screenshots and still display the video on the GUI?

Comment: @eyllanesc thanks for pointing that out. I hope the new edit is easier to understand.

Comment: Do you understand what an MCVE is? if you do not know what it is please read the link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved this by calling the pause function every time the video plays, and then playing the part of the video where it was paused when the play button is pressed.

here's the code:

```
def screenshotCall(self):
        #Call video frame grabber
        self.grabber = VideoFrameGrabber(self.videoWidget, self)
        self.mediaPlayer.setVideoOutput(self.grabber)
        self.grabber.frameAvailable.connect(self.process_frame)
        self.errorLabel.setText("Taking a screenshot of image "+str(self.counter)+" ....")
        self.mediaPlayer.pause()

def play(self):
    if self.mediaPlayer.state() == QMediaPlayer.PlayingState:
        self.mediaPlayer.pause()
    else:
        self.mediaPlayer.play()
        self.mediaPlayer.setVideoOutput(self.videoWidget)
```