# Attribute Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling must be set before QCoreApplication is created PyQt

Tags: pyqt5

I get this error ->

```
Attribute Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling must be set before QCoreApplication is created
```

when I want to run the code that isma put in the answer section in this question

[PyQt5 access frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52359924/pyqt5-access-frames-with-qmediaplayer)

how can i fix it?

Comment: Try removing `app.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.AA_EnableHighDpiScaling)` after `app` is created, as it's redundant and wrong.

Comment: Now it runs, but I get another error
I have the sound of the video but the video is not displayed
and gives this error `DeprecationWarning: an integer is required (got type sip.voidptr).  Implicit conversion to integers using __int__ is deprecated, and may be removed in a future version of Python.
  image = QImage(cloneFrame.bits(), cloneFrame.width(), cloneFrame.height()` @musicamante